# React: Multiple Ways to Set State

Tags: reactjs, react-state

Are there two different ways of using State in React?

1. I just read a resource, and this is one method within a function

   ```
   const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState('');
   setSearchTerm('abc');
   ```
2. Another uses this.state property

   ```
   this.state ..

   this.setState({
       searchTerm: 'abc' // enter values here
    });
   ```

When should I utilize these two methods? I am using React 16 with functions and inquiring about the difference.

Comment: One is for function components (the first) and the other is for class components (the second). The type of component you have will dictate which you should use. [Docs on Function and Class Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components)

Comment: I am using functions @BrianThompson

Comment: hi @BrianThompson feel free to write in answer if you want, and I can send points, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using these States depends on your component.

If you use `functional component`, you can use

```
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState('');
setSearchTerm('abc');
```

Or, If you use `class component`, You can use

```
this.state ..

this.setState({
    searchTerm: 'abc' // enter values here
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

First one is a react hook and used in functional components. If you are creating functional components then you have to use a hook to use state.

Second one is used in class components. If you are creating a class component then you use a state object and then update the state by using `this.setState`